# Prioritise private pypi server inside venv

Tags: python, azure-devops, pip

I use `pip` to install packages local and on venv. Recently, I modified the pip.config in order to implement private pypi solution and bumped into a problem.

We're creating a package named `foo`, uploaded it to private pypi server that hosted under Azure DevOps artifacts, using `twine`.

When downloading the package everything works fine with pip install on my local machine using the following `pip.conf:`

```
[global]
index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple
extra-index-url=https://<name of PAT>:<PAT>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<URL of Artifact Server>/
```

for some reason when creating `venv` [pip package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), one of the dependency for `foo` is `werkzeug`, and when trying to download it refers to the Private PyPi and not from official PyPi server.

`Not Found for url: https://<Private PyPi URL>/pypi/simple/werkzeug/`

> Using pip v21.0.1 and python 3.6.9

I'm trying to achieve that the dependencies for `foo` will be downloaded from Official pypi.python.org and only `foo` will be downloaded from the private pypi server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-behavior?view=azure-devops&tabs=nuget

To enable the new upstream behavior, select a package from within your feed then select the toggle button to **Allow external sourced versions**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your Artifact Repository in Azure configured to mirror from PyPi?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops

Check option `Include packages from common public sources`

Comment: you mean the upstream connection?